# fill area determined by coordinates labeled with "pin"s

Tags: tikz-pgf

a basis of one of my (complex) images is area determined by set of coordinates:

[image]

since this coordinates i use in further construction of images, i like in phase of drawings labeled them wit `pin=<...>:<coordinate name>`.  adding pins to coordinates, the area fill become strange:

[image]

this i can eliminated with first determining of coordinates and then draw contour, but this complicate my drawing process :-(. is there another (simple) way to eliminate this "disturbance" of the fill area?

```
    \documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[pin=120:A1] (A1) at ( 0, 0.0);
    \coordinate[pin= 60:A2,below right=5.6 and 14 of A1] (A2);
    \coordinate[pin=240:A3,below=12 of A1] (A3);
    % grid
    \draw[blue!25,dashed,thin]     (A1) grid[step=1] + (14,-12);
    \draw[blue!50,thin]            (A1) grid[step=2] + (14,-12);
    % podboj (surovec)
    \draw[fill=brown!30, fill opacity=0.5, draw opacity=1, thick]
       (A1) -| ++ ( 6.0,-1.6)   coordinate  (sa)
            -- ++ ( 2.8, 0.0)   coordinate  (sb)
            -| ++ ( 3.2,-1.6)   coordinate  (sc)
            -- ++ ( 0.0,-0.8)   coordinate  (sd)
            -| (A2)
            |- ++ (-1.0,-1.4)   coordinate  (x)
            |- ++ (-4.4,-5.0)   coordinate  (se)
            |- ++ (-6.0, 2.0)   coordinate  (sf)
            |- (A3) -- (A1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[pin=120:A1] (A1) at ( 0, 0.0);
    \coordinate[pin= 60:A2,below right=5.6 and 14 of A1] (A2);
    \coordinate[pin=240:A3,below=12 of A1] (A3);
    % grid
    \draw[blue!25,dashed,thin]     (A1) grid[step=1] + (14,-12);
    \draw[blue!50,thin]            (A1) grid[step=2] + (14,-12);
    % podboj (surovec)
    \draw[fill=brown!30, fill opacity=0.5, draw opacity=1, thick]
       (A1) -| ++ ( 6.0,-1.6)   coordinate[pin=60:sa]   (sa)
            -- ++ ( 2.8, 0.0)   coordinate[pin=60:sb]   (sb)
            -| ++ ( 3.2,-1.6)   coordinate[pin=60:sc]   (sc)
            -- ++ ( 0.0,-0.8)   coordinate[pin=60:sd]   (sd)
            -| (A2)
            |- ++ (-1.0,-1.4)   coordinate[pin=300:x]   (x)
            |- ++ (-4.4,-5.0)   coordinate[pin=240:se]  (se)
            |- ++ (-6.0, 2.0)   coordinate[pin= 60:sf]  (sf)
            |- (A3) -- (A1);
    \draw[dashed,red,thick]
       (sb) |- (sc);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

**addendum:**

if someone is interested ...

i extensive tested the solution provided by [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow) (see his answer below). in all tests i hadn't notice any side effect. in test i use his solution on the following way:

- in preamble i add

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{make append after command safe/.style={/tikz/append after command/.code=%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@after@path\expandafter{%
    \tikz@after@path\pgfextra{\pgfinterruptpath\path##1;\endpgfinterruptpath}}},
      every label/.append style = {align=center},
        every pin/.append style = {make append after command safe,
                                   pin distance=7mm, pin edge={blue,solid},
                                   text opacity=1 % for cases, if underlying drawings are (semi)transparent
                                   },
```

- in a `tikzpicture` use coordinates with pins on usual way:

```
\draw[fill=brown!30, fill opacity=0.5, draw opacity=1, thick]
   (A1) -| ++ ( 6.0,-1.6)   coordinate  (sa)
        -- ++ ( 2.8, 0.0)   coordinate  (sb)
        -| ++ ( 3.2,-1.6)   coordinate  (sc)
        -- ++ ( 0.0,-0.8)   coordinate  (sd)
        -| (A2)
        |- ++ (-1.0,-1.4)   coordinate  (x)
        |- ++ (-4.4,-5.0)   coordinate  (se)
        |- ++ (-6.0, 2.0)   coordinate  (sf)
        |- (A3) -- (A1);
```

Comment: A TikZ feature? :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX, probably. or malfunction/bug? quite disturbing me.

Comment: "Feature" is David Carlisle's way to say "bug" :):):)

Comment: It works with `label`, but not with `pin`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., this can be solution, if there is no way to works with `pin`. in cases when coordinates are very close, labels aren't so handy as pins, so i still have a hope, that this will be resolved (one day :-) ).

Comment: I would guess it doesn't work because `pin` adds an `edge`, and the `edge` somehow messes up the filling path. Whether this is expected behaviour (due to the `edge`) or a bug, I cannot say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit of digging shows that the pin option uses `append after command` which doesn't seem to protect any existing path.

There may be good reasons for this approach, but a workaround in this case (which may have side-affects in other code) is to redefine the `append after command` key to protect the path using `\pgfinterruptpath...\endpgfinterruptpath`. The following solution/workaround places this redefinition inside another key so it can be used within a scope or a single path:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{make append after command safe/.style={/tikz/append after command/.code=%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@after@path\expandafter{%
    \tikz@after@path\pgfextra{\pgfinterruptpath\path##1;\endpgfinterruptpath}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[pin=120:A1] (A1) at ( 0, 0.0);
\coordinate[pin= 60:A2,below right=5.6 and 14 of A1] (A2);
\coordinate[pin=240:A3,below=12 of A1] (A3);

\draw[blue!25,dashed,thin]     (A1) grid[step=1] + (14,-12);
\draw[blue!50,thin]            (A1) grid[step=2] + (14,-12);
% podboj (surovec)
\draw[make append after command safe, 
  fill=brown!30, fill opacity=0.5, draw opacity=1, thick]
   (A1) -| ++ ( 6.0,-1.6)   coordinate[pin=60:sa]   (sa)
        -- ++ ( 2.8, 0.0)   coordinate[pin=60:sb]   (sb)
        -| ++ ( 3.2,-1.6)   coordinate[pin=60:sc]   (sc)
        -- ++ ( 0.0,-0.8)   coordinate[pin=60:sd]   (sd)
        -| (A2)
        |- ++ (-1.0,-1.4)   coordinate[pin=300:x]   (x)
        |- ++ (-4.4,-5.0)   coordinate[pin=240:se]  (se)
        |- ++ (-6.0, 2.0)   coordinate[pin= 60:sf]  (sf)
        |- (A3) -- (A1);
\draw[dashed,red,thick] (sb) |- (sc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! it works! I hope that this solution once be part of TikZ :-).